Error using Expo Push Notification API from Java server
I'm trying to implement Expo Push Notification for my ReactNative app (both iOS/Android). I can send and receive remote push notification both using Expo Push Notification Tool (https://expo.dev/notifications) and using terminal with:
curl -X POST https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{
   "to": "ExponentPushToken[**********************]",
   "sound": "default",
   "title": "Title",
   "body": "Body"
 }'

The problem comes while I was trying to send push notification from my Java web application; this is my code:
try {
            
            for(DevicePushNotification devicePushNotification : expoList) {
            
                URL url = new URL("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
              
                String jsonInputString = "{"
                        + "\"to\": \"" + devicePushNotification.getToken() + "\","
                        + "\"sound\": \"default\","
                        + "\"title\": \"EasyTeleMed HOME\","
                        + "\"body\": \"Test\""
                        + "}";
                
                logger.info("Request --> " + jsonInputString);
                
                try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
                    
                    byte[] input = jsonInputString.getBytes("utf-8");
                    os.write(input, 0, input.length);
                }
                
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                logger.info("Response Code --> " + responseCode);

             
                BufferedReader in;
                if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 300) {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                } else {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), "utf-8"));
                }

                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    resp.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                
                // Mostra il messaggio di risposta
                logger.info("Response Message --> " + resp.toString());
                
                conn.disconnect();              
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            
            logger.error("Error during sending Expo push notification --> " + e.getMessage());
        }

My server logs shows the following:
Request --> {"to": "ExponentPushToken[**********************]","sound": "default","title": "EasyTeleMed HOME","body": "Test"}

Response Code --> 400
Response Message --> {"errors":[{"code":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"\"to\" is required.","isTransient":false,"requestId":"ff054b5c-d0d6-4bbd-9742-c8bd3a299e2d"}]}

I think I'm missing something on the formatting of my request, because the request data looks good.
Any suggestions?

Your implementation looks correct to me. Based on the error, the to value might be null. Could you add a log to check the value?
logger.info("Token --> " + devicePushNotification.getToken());

Thanks, but I find the solution, the problem was the "utf-8" in the content type property: I find it suggested everywhere, but removing that from the property resolves the problem
